Is $f(x+iy) = x$ not differentiable?
Sorry if this is really basic, but I want an answer.
Let $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be given by $f(x + iy) = x.\ $  Not the absolute value $\lvert x \rvert$, just x.$\ $  This seems like it should be very well-behaved and differentiable, but it does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 1 \neq \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0 $$
Similarly, checking the limit directly from the real and imaginary directions gives two different results at every point z = x +iy.
$$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}f = \frac{x + \Delta x - x}{\Delta x} = 1 \neq \lim_{\Delta y \rightarrow 0}f = \frac{x - x}{i\Delta y} = 0 $$
As a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}²$ this doesn't seem problematic for the two different directional derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} $ to have different values.$\ $  I know that being complex differentiable is a stricter requirement than as a real function of two real variables, I think my problem is that $f(z) = x$ seems like such a nice function:$\ $  a plane through the origin.$\ $  Smooth, no edges or corners.

Note that $\Re(z) = (z + \bar z )/2$ if it was différentiable , si would $\bar z$

The basic rule is $f$ is "differentiable" if $df$ is a multiple of $dz$, with no $d\overline{z}$ coefficient. That's all the Cauchy–Riemann equations really say. Here $df=\frac12dz+\frac12d\overline{z}$. As you said, complex differentiability is a strict requirement. Sure, $dz$ and $df$ can be thought of as vectors in $\Bbb R^2$, and a linear map relates them. But such maps have $4$ degrees of freedom, whereas a complex $dz$ coefficient we can call $f'$ only has $2$.

@JyrkiLahtonen I am not sure where the bend is.  By $\mathbb{C}^2 $ I assume you mean combining the input and output space (direct product?).  In the analogous case of $\mathbb{R}^4$  the solution set to $ f(x,y) = (x,0) $ is a plane (2d surface) in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

@J.G. to make sure I'm following you, by "no $d\overline{z}$ coefficient" you mean $df = adz + bd\overline{z}$?  Are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?  Why talk about 4 degrees of freedom?  For the real function $ f(x,y) = (x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ f only has two degrees of freedom?

Would it follow that any function $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ is not complex differentiable?  ie any function that collapses/projects all complex inputs to the real line.

$a,,b$ are complex-valued functions. Over $\Bbb R$, they each have $2$ degrees of freedom for a total of $4$. In your example, $df=(c_1+c_2i)dz+(c_3+c_4i)dz$ with the real-valued $c_j$ given by $c_1=c_3=\frac12,,c_2=c_4=0$ (more generally they're not constant). A collapse-to-real function has $v=0$ so to solve the CREs it needs constant $u$, i.e. constant $f$.

Correct, the only complex differentiable functions $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{R}$ are the constant functions.

I find the case of $f(z) = \overline{z}$ more palatable because the surface is "torn" at $z = 0$, looking more like a jump discontinuity like $g(x) = 0$ for $ \leq 0$ and $g(x) = 1$ for $x > 0$.  For $f(z) = \overline{z}$, as we approach from $\mathbb{R}^+, f'(z) = 1$, and as $\Delta z \rightarrow 0$ from $i, f'(z) = -1$, from the $1 + i$ direction it's $i$, and it smoothly changes between them as you go around with the direction of approach.  So there is a big jump discontinuity at the point where you're trying to differentiate.
